# Seeking SA Suburbs GIS shapefile?

Tags: data, south-africa

Can you provide a link to the South Africa Suburbs shapefile or specifically to the Umgungundlovu District Suburbs shapefile?

I have browsed the demarcation board but it is not available on http://www.demarcation.org.za/index.php/downloads/boundary-data/ .

Comment: If it’s open data that you seek then I think the place to ask is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Comment: I AM LOOKING FOR THE SHAPEFILE OF THE DISTRICT NOT A DATA . I HAVE A SPATIAL DATA WHICH I WANT TO LOAD INTO THE DISTRICT SHAPEFILE FOR ANALYSIS. PLEASE NEED HELP

Comment: This community would like to help you, but we are human beings, not mind readers. Your question is confusing. Please use the [edit] link under the question to clarify your question. Are you trying to convert spatial data into shapefile format?

Answer (score 0):

I have never come across suburb geospatial data per se. You could try get hold of Statistics South Africa and enquire if you can get sub-place or small area data that they use for Census but even those won't exactly match suburb boundaries. You could also try get hold of some erven data from the Department of Rural Development and Land Reform.

Answer (score 0):

i saw this but doesn't look like the 2 localmunicipanity Great Edendale and Vulindlela

http://www.demarcation.org.za/site/documents/2016-boundaries-local-municipalities/